# Previous fragment visible below current fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I'm currently making an app that has one root activity and changes layout by replacing the fragment in a FrameLayout container. In my root activity I'm using the method below to replace fragments. I navigate to a login page with this method, and use a similar method without the addToBackStack to go to the user's account overview screen. When I press the back button the app does what I want, it navigates to the root view instead of the login screen (because I did not add that to the back stack), but the account overview fragment is still visible below the root fragment. How to solve this?

I tried a couple of solutions I could find, but failed to solve my problem. The weird thing is once I press the back button the account overview fragment does not call onPause/onDestroy or anything, it actualy does that when I try to navigate to the login page again after going back to the root. It is as if it is one step behind what is actualy going on, pausing one view later than it should.

```
public void navigateTo(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction =   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out, R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
    transaction.replace(R.id.content_container, fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack("");
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: remove transaction.addToBackStack("");

Comment: I already tried doing it without addTobackStack for everything, but unfortunately without any luck